# Drawing repeatedly updating images to the canvas (Safari blanks out image during loading)

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari

I'm drawing an image onto the background of a canvas. This image refreshes every second, but the canvas needs to be redrawn more often than that, every 0.5 seconds. The problem I seem to be running into is that Safari flickers when updating the canvas because it appears to lose the image data from the bgImg variable. Firefox works as expected and no flicker occurs.

Does anyone have any clue as to how to avoid this? Am I missing something really obvious?

To test this code, simply paste the entire code below into an html file and load with your browser. What it should do is:

- create a canvas
- load an image every second
- redraw the canvas every 500ms, using the image as a background.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var bgImg = new Image();
var firstload = false;
var cv;
var ctx;

var updateBackground = function() {
    bgImg.onload = function() {
      firstload = true;
      console.log("image loaded. Dimensions are " + bgImg.width + "x" + bgImg.height);
    }
    bgImg.src = "http://mopra-ops.atnf.csiro.au/TOAD/temp.php?" + Math.random() * 10000000;
    setTimeout(updateBackground, 1000);
  }

  var initGraphics = function() {
    cv = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = cv.getContext("2d");
    cv.width = cv.clientWidth;
    cv.height = cv.clientHeight;
    cv.top = 0;
    cv.left = 0;  
  }

  var drawStuff = function() {
    console.log("Draw called. firstload = " + firstload );
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cv.width, cv.height);
    if ( firstload == true) {
      console.log("Drawing image. Dimensions are " + bgImg.width + "x" + bgImg.height);
      try {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImg, 0, 0);                
      } catch(err) {
        console.log('Oops! Something bad happened: ' + err);
      }
    }
    setTimeout(drawStuff, 500);
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    initGraphics();
    setTimeout(updateBackground, 1000);
    setTimeout(drawStuff, 500);
    }
    </script>

    <style>
body    {
   background: #000000;
   font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 10px;
   color: #cccccc;
   }

.maindisplay {
       position:absolute;
       top:    3%;
       left:   1%;
       height: 96%;
       width: 96%;
       text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
       </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myspan" style="width: 50%">
<canvas id="canvas" class="maindisplay"></canvas>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just as a note, your `setTimeout()` calls should look like `setTimeout(drawStuff)` - no reason to pass a string like that.

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3XW8q/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are drawing `bgImg` while it's loading. Webkit does not cache the old image data while loading a new image; it wipes out the image as soon as a new `.src` is set.

You can fix this by using two images, using the last-valid-loaded one for drawing while the next one is loading.

I've put an example of this online here: http://jsfiddle.net/3XW8q/2/

Simplified for Stack Overflow posterity:

```
var imgs=[new Image,new Image], validImage, imgIndex=0;

function initGraphics() {
  // Whenever an image loads, record it as the latest-valid image for drawing
  imgs[0].onload = imgs[1].onload = function(){ validImage = this; };
}

function loadNewImage(){
  // When it's time to load a new image, pick one you didn't last use
  var nextImage = imgs[imgIndex++ % imgs.length];
  nextImage.src = "..."+Math.random();
  setTimeout(loadNewImage, 2000);
}

function updateCanvas(){
  if (validImage){ // Wait for the first valid image to load
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(validImage, 0, 0);
  }
  setTimeout(updateCanvas, 500);
}
```